# Configuring modules for when an article is clicked in a category blog layout menu (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla, menu, module, position, joomla2.5

Suppose I have these three modules:

- `main_menu_module` (linked to a menu that has a `Home Page` link, and a `Sport articles Blog Layout` link)
- `module1`
- `module2`

The module `main_menu_module` should be shown in all pages (which is OK).

I want that:

`module1` be **ONLY** in **Blog Layout List** of `Sport` category, not when a ***single `Sport` article*** from that list was clicked.

`module2` be **ONLY** in ***single `Sport` article*** from that list, and **NOT** when the **Blog Layout LIST** was shown.

Now the question is:

**Is that possible at all using Joomla?** Even if that is not, no problem. I just want a link proving this fact.

Please ask me if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is clear and makes sense. This can be done in Joomla, but it requires an extension. Basic Joomla will not do this because of itemID inheritance. Any content item that does not directly have a menu item inherits the itemID from it's parent so a module assigned to the sport category will also display on the individual items in that category.

In order to solve this issue you need to install Advanced Module Manager. This allows you to have much finer control over where your module display, such as including or excluding child items when determining whether the module should display.

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

Comment: What settings in the advancedmodulemanager will do what is asked?

Comment: Here is a forum post on the nonumber website that answers the question: http://www.nonumber.nl/forum/AdvancedModuleManager/1203-Module-appearing-on-every-page#1203